# Insert line after match using sed

Tags: shell, sed

For some reason I can't seem to find a straightforward answer to this and I'm on a bit of a time crunch at the moment.  How would I go about inserting a choice line of text after the first line matching a specific string using the `sed` command.  I have ...

```
CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"
CLIENTFILE="bar"
```

And I want insert a line after the `CLIENTSCRIPT=` line resulting in ...

```
CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"
CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"
CLIENTFILE="bar"
```

Comment: If one needs capture groups to be used in the inserted line, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/39103787/520567

Answer (score 486, accepted):

Try doing this using GNU sed:

```
sed '/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/a CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' file
```

if you want to substitute *in-place*, use

```
sed -i '/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/a CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' file
```

### Output

```
CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"
CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"
CLIENTFILE="bar"
```

### Doc

- see [sed doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html) and search `\a` (append)

Comment: Thanks! And to get it to write back to the file without printing the contents of the file?

Comment: Note that both assume GNU `sed`. That's not standard `sed` syntax and won't work with any other `sed` implementation.

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work for me because I was using a different delimiter. After RTFM'ing, I realized I had to start the regex with a \, then the delimiter.

Comment: How would you modify the sed if the pattern inside the /.../ is a variable?

Comment: Invert single/double quotes ^^

Comment: How does it apply ONLY to the first match? it is clear that it append text after the match, but how does it know only to the first match?

Comment: This adds the text after every match, for me.

Comment: Doesn't work on OSX. I need it for a build script that can run on both Linux and OSX

Comment: Is the sed line works without the -i switch ? If yes, then, use -i'' Thanks to makes a reply, I will update my POST

Comment: Ist there a way to keep the intends?

Comment: @sdkks I've felt that pain, and it's awful.  There are ways around it using posix, but unless you're only writing a one-off script, it will be a constant source of agony.  You've probably long figured out a solution, but for any others, what I ended up doing was installed GNU sed with `brew` then referencing `gsed` in the script.  Some linux distros require `alias gsed='sed'` to make that work.

Comment: @Freedom_Ben I used `perl` instead. It was easier to figure out.

Comment: What if I want to use variable instead?

Comment: this does not allow add space

Answer (score 74):

Note the standard `sed` syntax (as in POSIX, so supported by all conforming `sed` implementations around (GNU, OS/X, BSD, Solaris...)):

```
sed '/CLIENTSCRIPT=/a\
CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' file
```

Or on one line:

```
sed -e '/CLIENTSCRIPT=/a\' -e 'CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' file
```

(`-e`xpressions (and the contents of `-f`iles) are joined with newlines to make up the sed script `sed` interprets).

The `-i` option for in-place editing is also a GNU extension, some other implementations (like FreeBSD's) support `-i ''` for that.

Alternatively, for portability, you can use `perl` instead:

```
perl -pi -e '$_ .= qq(CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"\n) if /CLIENTSCRIPT=/' file
```

Or you could use `ed` or `ex`:

```
printf '%s\n' /CLIENTSCRIPT=/a 'CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' . w q | ex -s file
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but the current `sed -e '/CLIENTSCRIPT=/a\' -e 'CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' file` escapes the quote at the end of the first parameter and breaks the command.

Comment: @AbandonedCart, in shells of the Bourne, `csh` or `rc` family, `'...'` are strong quotes inside which backslash is not special. The only exception that I know is the `fish` shell.

Comment: Terminal on MacOS (and subsequently a script run in terminal) is also an exception, apparently. I found alternate syntax, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @AbandonedCart, that's something else. That's macOS `sed` not being POSIX compliant here. That makes my statement about it being portable incorrect (for the one line variant). I'll ask the opengroup for confirmation if it's indeed a non-conformance or a misinterpretation of the standard on my part.

Comment: I had so many problems with different versions of sed that I tried the `printf...ex` version. This works like charm!

Answer (score 21):

Sed command that works on MacOS (at least, OS 10) and Unix alike (ie. doesn't require gnu sed like Gilles' (currently accepted) one does):

```
sed -e '/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/a\'$'\n''CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' file
```

This works in bash and maybe other shells too that know the $'\n' evaluation quote style. Everything can be on one line and work in 
 older/POSIX sed commands. If there might be multiple lines matching the CLIENTSCRIPT="foo" (or your equivalent) and you wish to only add the extra line the first time, you can rework it as follows:

```
sed -e '/^ *CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/b ins' -e b -e ':ins' -e 'a\'$'\n''CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"' -e ': done' -e 'n;b done' file
```

(this creates a loop after the line insertion code that just cycles through the rest of the file, never getting back to the first sed command again).

You might notice I added a '^ *' to the matching pattern in case that line shows up in a comment, say, or is indented. Its not 100% perfect but covers some other situations likely to be common. Adjust as required...

These two solutions also get round the problem (for the generic solution to adding a line) that if your new inserted line contains unescaped backslashes or ampersands they will be interpreted by sed and likely not come out the same, just like the `\n` is - eg. `\0` would be the first line matched. Especially handy if you're adding a line that comes from a variable where you'd otherwise have to escape everything first using ${var//} before, or another sed statement etc.

This solution is a little less messy in scripts (that quoting and \n is not easy to read though), when you don't want to put the replacement text for the a command at the start of a line if say, in a function with indented lines. I've taken advantage that $'\n' is evaluated to a newline by the shell, its not in regular '\n' single-quoted values.

Its getting long enough though that I think perl/even awk might win due to being more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! First one works like a charm on AIX OS as well.

Comment: how do you do this but for multi-line insertion?

Comment: POSIX sed supports literal newlines in the replacement string if you "escape" them with a backslash ([source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1p.html)). So: `s/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/&\ ` **[Enter]** `CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"/`. The backslash has to be the very last character on the line (no whitespace after it), contrary to how it looks in this comment.

Comment: @tatsu Newlines in the replacement string of `s///`, as well as those in the `a` and `i` commands can be "escaped," using the same method I describe in my comment above.

Answer (score 20):

A POSIX compliant one using the `s` command:

```
sed '/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/s/.*/&\
CLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"/' file
```

Comment: ...that even supports inserting new lines. I love it!

Comment: See also `sed -e '/.../s/$/\' -e 'CLI.../'` which would avoid problems with lines that contain byte sequences not forming valid characters.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe a bit late to post an answer for this, but I found some of the above solutions a bit cumbersome.

I tried simple string replacement in sed and it worked:

```
sed 's/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/&\nCLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"/' file
```

**&** sign reflects the matched string, and then you add \n and the new line.

As mentioned, if you want to do it in-place:

```
sed -i 's/CLIENTSCRIPT="foo"/&\nCLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"/' file
```

Another thing. You can match using an expression:

```
sed -i 's/CLIENTSCRIPT=.*/&\nCLIENTSCRIPT2="hello"/' file
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: This works fine on Linux, where GNU sed is default, because it understands `\n` in the replacement string. Plain-vanilla (POSIX) `sed` does _not_ understand `\n` in the replacement string, however, so this won't work on BSD or macOS—unless you've installed GNU sed somehow. With vanilla sed you _can_ embed newlines by "escaping" them—that is, ending the line with a backslash, then pressing **[Enter]** ([reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1p.html), under the heading for `[2addr]s/BRE/replacement/flags`). This means your sed command has to span multiple lines in the terminal.

Comment: Another option to get a literal newline in the replacement string is to use the [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) feature in Bash, as mentioned in [one of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48406504/785213).

Answer (score 7):

The awk variant :

```
awk '1;/CLIENTSCRIPT=/{print "CLIENTSCRIPT2=\"hello\""}' file
```

Comment: For anyone wondering about the `1;`, see [Why does “1” in awk print the current line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262869/why-does-1-in-awk-print-the-current-line)

Comment: Thanks, how to only print after first match?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task, and was not able to get the above perl solution to work.

Here is my solution:

`perl -i -pe "BEGIN{undef $/;} s/^\[mysqld\]$/[mysqld]\n\ncollation-server = utf8_unicode_ci\n/sgm" /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

**Explanation:**

Uses a regular expression to search for a line in my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file that contained only `[mysqld]` and replaced it with

`[mysqld]
 collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci`

effectively adding the `collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci` line after the line containing `[mysqld]`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently as well for both Mac and Linux OS's and after browsing through many posts and trying many things out, in my particular opinion I never got to where I wanted to which is: a simple enough to understand solution using well known and standard commands with simple patterns, one liner, portable, expandable to add in more constraints. Then I tried to looked at it with a different perspective, that's when I realized i could do without the "one liner" option if a "2-liner" met the rest of my criteria. At the end I came up with this solution I like that works in both Ubuntu and Mac which i wanted to share with everyone:

```
insertLine=$(( $(grep -n "foo" sample.txt | cut -f1 -d: | head -1) + 1 ))
sed -i -e "$insertLine"' i\'$'\n''bar'$'\n' sample.txt
```

In first command, grep looks for line numbers containing "foo", cut/head selects 1st occurrence, and the arithmetic op increments that first occurrence line number by 1 since I want to insert after the occurrence.
In second command, it's an in-place file edit, "i" for inserting: an ansi-c quoting new line, "bar", then another new line. The result is adding a new line containing "bar" after the "foo" line. Each of these 2 commands can be expanded to more complex operations and matching.