# How to append just one line after found match with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I want to append `'maildomain'` after the line `port` in a php file. I really want to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-first-match-using-sed) as this seems the cleanest and very clear so I did

```
sed -i "350,/port/a \'maildomain\'" file.php
```

but it came out like this :

```
351 : 'maildomain'
352 : 
353 : 'maildomain'
354 : 
...
358 : blablabla port blabla
359 : 'maildomain'
```

As you can see, it adds `'maildomain'` alternately from line 350 until it found `port` which is located at line 354 initially. How do I modify the sed command above to just add `'maildomain'` after `port` and not before it? Thank you.

Also, when use line 353 instead of 350, it gives me this :

```
353 : 'maildomain'
354 : balsdbflasdbflsd port blablablabla
355 : 'maildomain'
```

Why? Thanks~

Comment: `350,/port/` means each line starting from `350` until the line that matches `/port/`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Don't you see `blablabl port blabla`?

Comment: Try `sed -i "/port/a \'maildomain\'" file.php`.

Comment: Have you tried `sed -e's/port/port\n\'maildomain\'/g' file.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to add `'maildomain'` after any line that contains `port` then [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23903014/970195) has the right answer. However, if you have many such lines that contains `port` and only wish to add after line number 350 then you can do the following:

```
sed -i "350,/port/{
    /port/a \'maildomain\'
}" file.php
```

This will look for lines after line number 350 and any line that has `port` in it, it will append `'maildomain'` after it. Notice how I have split the command on multiple lines. You need to do that as well. It is due to the fact that the `a` command in `sed` requires an actual newline character.

If you only wish to add it once after line number 350 then you can branch out `b` after you are done adding.

```
sed -i "350,/port/{
    /port/a \'maildomain\'
    b;
}" file.php
```

Comment: Lol I just commented on Barmar's answer before I saw this. Your answer is what I wanted but I got this error : `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'` when I tried to compact it to one line and run it. I really need to compact it because I'm planning to use it in my C code, not in a shell script. 

How do I compact it? Thank you!

Comment: @user3526156 Ok, try `sed "350,/port/{/port/N;s/\n/\nmaildomain\n/}" file.php`. This should work for your case.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me! Saved my hair. ;)

Answer (score 5):

An address of the form `x,y` means all the lines from `x` through `y` inclusive, so `350,/port/` means each line from `350` through the line that matches the `/port/` regexp.

If you only want to append after the `/port/` line, just specify that address:

```
sed -i "/port/a \'maildomain\'" file.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I also want to start replacing only the first matched word after line 350 because I have many other words `port` in my file. How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your requirements properly, you can do this in sed using Barmar's solution.

Or you could use awk:

```
awk '1;/port/{print "maildomain"}'
```

This prints the current line, and then tests to see if the current line includes your keyword, and if it does, prints the extra line.

Or, since you've mentioned the `bash` tag, you could do this in pure bash:

```
while read line; do echo "$line"; [[ $line =~ port ]] && echo "maildomain"; done
```

This implements exactly the same logic as the `awk` solution, but without launching an external interpreter.

Comment: awk...interesting. Thanks for the bash solution though~ Aprreciate it. ;)