# Sed append regex capture groups

Tags: regex, bash, sed, capture-group

If someone can please assist, I'm trying to do a sed append using regex and capture groups but its not working fully:

```
echo "#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/" | sed -re '/#baseurl=http:\/\/mirror.centos.org(.*)/a baseurl=https:\/\/10.10.10.10\ \1'
 #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos//contrib//
 baseurl=https://10.10.10.10 1
```

At the moment it is just giving the literal value 1 rather than the capture group.

It should give:

```
 #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos//contrib//
 baseurl=https://10.10.10.10/centos//contrib//
```

I have tried backslash parentheses as well but its not working. Please assist....as it is hurting my head now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only capture back-reference when using `s` (substitute) command in `sed`.

This should working:

```
s="#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/"    
sed -r 's~#baseurl=http://mirror\.centos\.org(.*)~&\nbaseurl=https://10.10.10.10\1~' <<< "$s"

#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos//contrib//
baseurl=https://10.10.10.10/centos//contrib//
```

Comment: Very nicely done (I +1'd before). Why is this that back-references are just to be used in substitute mode? I could not find a reference on this.

Comment: I believe other than substitute mode only `/search/` allows use of regex and groups and as there is no replacement there we cannot use back-reference.

Comment: Thanks, I did sed with s and did two capture groups (...(.*)) and just printed \1\nxyz\2 which is more or less the same as yours! Thanks anyway!