# sed to insert a text line after first match only & remove n lines after second match using sed only

Tags: bash, sed, insert

For first question, example,

```
A  
B  
C  
B  
D
```

Need to insert E after **FIRST MATCH** of `B`.

```
A  
B  
E  
C  
B  
D
```

---

For second question example,

```
A  
B  
C  
B  
D  
E  
F
```

Need to remove only D and E, 2 lines after **second pattern match**.

```
A  
B  
C  
B  
F
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert line after first match using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-first-match-using-sed) Even though it really has two questions making it a bit broader... Perhaps it could still be salvaged with a little refocusing? Also showing some effort towards a solution never hurts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/B/!b;x;s/^/x/;/^x\{1\}$/{x;aE' -e 'b};x' file

sed -e '/B/!b;x;s/^/x/;/^x\{2\}$/{x;n;N;d};x' file
```

Both these solutions can be split into three parts:

- Focus on a particuar regexp
- Counting
- Conditional on the above

If the regexp is not true, continue as normal

If the regexp is true, count it by appending a character (`x`) to the hold space for each occurrence.

Condtional on the count (in the first solution, 1 and the second solution, 2) carry out an action.

In the first solution:

- append a line containing `E`

In the second solution:

- print the current line
- append the next two lines
- delete the current pattern space

If the conditional  is not true, continue as normal.

N.B. the first solution can be shortened using ranges:

```
sed '0,/B/!b;//aE' file
```

or for variations of sed that do not allow GNU extentions (`0,address`)

```
sed -e '/B/{aE' -e ':a;n;ba}' file
```

Comment: Nice solution! A bit shorter than mine ;-) +1!

Answer (score 1):

Implementation done with

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

**Q1:**

```
$ more input
A
B
C
B
D
B
D
```

**sed:**

```
$ sed -n -e '/^B$/!{p};/^B$/{p;x;/^$/{a E' -e '}}' input
A
B
E
C
B
D
B
D
```

**Q2:**

```
$ more input2
A
B
C
B
D
E
F
```

**sed:**

```
$ sed -n '/^B$/{p;H};/^B$/!{x;/B\nB1\?$/{s/.*/&1/;x;b;};x;p}' input2
A
B
C
B
F
```