# Using sed to add a line after a specific string, can't make it work for strings involving ' ( / etc

Tags: unix, awk, sed, terminal

Im trying to use sed to add a line after a specific string in a file. Can anyone help?

**File name:**

```
example.js
```

**Existing line:**

```
localeData: require('react-intl/locale-data/en'),
```

**Desired output:**

```
localeData: require('react-intl/locale-data/en'),
messages: require('../locale/messages_en'),
```

UPDATE:
Some progress, this command replaces the string being searched with the string I want appended.I don't want it replaced:

```
sed 's/react-intl\/locale-data\/en/..\/locale\/messages_en/g' example.js
```

Comment: updated

@anubhava no not limited to using sed, any command that required no manual intervention (this is part of a script). Sed is just the overwhelming majority of results when searching 'how to add a line after a specific string in a file'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert line after first match using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-first-match-using-sed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this non-regex way using `awk`:

```
awk -v s="localeData: require('react-intl/locale-data/en')," \
    -v r="messages: require('../locale/messages_en')," '
1
index($0, s) {
   print r
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `a` operator to insert a line after a matched line in `sed`:

```
sed '/react-intl\/locale-data\/en/a messages:   require('..\/locale\/messages_en'),' example.js
```

`react-intl\/locale-data\/en` matches a line with `react-intl/locale-data/en`  string in it, and `a messages:   require('..\/locale\/messages_en'),` inserts `messages:   require('../locale/messages_en'),` right below.