# How to search and then add after a block of a multiline text with specific chars in it

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I need a general solution, if possible with `sed` util, to find a multiline block of text. The text is not known in advance and it might contain specific symbols, so I cannot escape symbols. This block must be considered as a raw text.

Then I need to insert into the file, another block of text, which also might contain different specific chars, not known in advance.

Here is an example. Original file which contains several `qq§$<>ui` lines:

```
line1
line2
qq§$<>ui
klfd</de>
qq§$<>ui
line gg
qq§$<>ui
line aaa
qq§$<>ui
line bbb
lastButOneLine
lastLine
```

Text to search:

```
qq§$<>ui
klfd</de>
```

Text to add after it:

```
qq§$<>ui
another2ndLine</de>combination
```

The result:

```
line1
line2
qq§$<>ui
klfd</de>
qq§$<>ui
another2ndLine</de>combination
qq§$<>ui
line gg
qq§$<>ui
line aaa
qq§$<>ui
line bbb
lastButOneLine
lastLine
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get the text, and why does it have to be multiline text?

Try checking here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-first-match-using-sed

Answer (score 2):

Assume `ip.txt` is the input file, `f1` has the input string to search and `f2` has the string to be added.

With `perl` (worked for given sample, not sure if some other unicode characters can cause issues)

```
a="$(< f1)" b="$(< f2)" perl -0777 -pe 's/\Q$ENV{a}\E\K/\n$ENV{b}/g' ip.txt
```

`\Q` and `\E` will protect input from being interpreted as regex metacharacters

---

With `GNU sed`, assuming input doesn't have ASCII NUL characters.

```
$ # escape all BRE metacharacters
$ # replace literal newlines with \n
$ sed -z 's#[[^$*.\/]#\\&#g; s/\n/\\n/g' f1
qq§\$<>ui\nklfd<\/de>\n

$ # escape all replacement section metacharacters for f2
$ # and add trailing \ for literal newlines
$ sed 's:[\\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/' f2
qq§$<>u$i\
another2ndLine<\/de>combination
```

With that working, you can then use `sed -z` again for actual modification:

```
$ search="$(sed -z 's#[[^$*.\/]#\\&#g; s/\n/\\n/g' f1)"
$ repl="$(sed 's:[\\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/' f2)"
$ sed -z 's/'"$search"'/&'"$repl"'\n/g' ip.txt
line1
line2
qq§$<>ui
klfd</de>
qq§$<>u$i
another2ndLine</de>combination
qq§$<>ui
line gg
qq§$<>ui
line aaa
qq§$<>ui
line bbb
lastButOneLine
lastLine
```

---

With [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```
rg -N --passthru -UF "$(< f1)" -r '$0'$'\n'"$(sed 's/\$/$$/g' f2)" ip.txt
```

- `-N` to prevent line numbers in output
- `--passthru` to allow all input lines to be printed, whether or not they match the search condition
- `-UF` enable multiline match and fixed string match
- `"$(< f1)"` input string to search, note that trailing newline will be removed
- `-r '$0'$'\n'"$(sed 's/\$/$$/g' f2)"` replacement string

  - `$0` the string that was matched
  - `$'\n'` to add trailing newline that was removed earlier
  - `"$(sed 's/\$/$$/g' f2)"` content of `f2` with `$` escaped as `$$`

See [my blog post](https://learnbyexample.github.io/substitution-with-ripgrep/) for more details about search and replacment with `rg` command.

Answer (score 1):

@Sundeep, @stevesliva, thank you for your effort. Both solutions are a bit complex to me and I needed something that is less complicated.

If to consider a solution as a function, than the simplest one should accept only 3 parameters:

1. file path,
2. search block of text,
3. insert block of text.

As a consumer/client I do not want to know **HOW** to solve, rather only to know **WHAT** to pass to the solution.

`regexp` is a very might solution, but if you do not work with them regularly it takes more time to maintain them and use.

I've created a small java application. For my environment, running java is not an issue. Here is how it could be invoked:

```
java -jar insert-unique-after.jar \
  --path some.txt \
  --insert-after "line1
  line2
    line3" \
  --insert-text "line4
  line5
  line6"
```

It is simple and clear. And that was my choice.

For those who want to try it, here is a git project: [insert-after](https://github.com/AlexandrSokolov/insert-after) and a built executable jar file: [insert-unique-after.jar](https://github.com/AlexandrSokolov/ansible_java_generators/blob/master/files/insert-unique-after.jar)

I am sure that it is also very simple to implement it on any modern programming languages, without requirement to have `jre` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to dislike complicated regexes.  It's not simple, but you can pipeline from grep results to construct a simple sed command to do the replacement.

File to search is `file`, lines to add are in `add.txt`.

First, find all of the second lines, with prior line and line numbers included in output:

```
$ grep -nFB1 'klfd</de>' file
3-qq§$<>ui
4:klfd</de>
```

Second, find only lines where the first line preceded the second line:

```
$ grep -nFB1 'klfd</de>' file | grep -FA1 -- '-qq§$<>ui'
3-qq§$<>ui
4:klfd</de>
```

Third, turn that output into a simple sed `r` command for each matching line:

```
$ grep -nFB1 'klfd</de>' file | grep -FA1 -- '-qq§$<>ui' | sed -n '/^[0-9]*:/{s/:.*/r add.txt\n/;P}'
4r add.txt
```

Finally, run the above command on `file` with `sed -f-` to take commands from stdin.

```
$ echo ADD THIS > add.txt

$ grep -nFB1 'klfd</de>' file | grep -FA1 -- '-qq§$<>ui' | sed -n '/^[0-9]*:/{s/:.*/r add.txt\n/;P}' | sed -f- file
line1
line2
qq§$<>ui
klfd</de>
ADD THIS
qq§$<>ui
line gg
qq§$<>ui
line aaa
qq§$<>ui
line bbb
lastButOneLine
lastLine
```