# Append data after every matched line in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I need to add after 1 line after match . Whenever there is a match this line should be added. In our case after `'{'` :

```
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/ked.log', "\n match", FILE_APPEND);
```

===================
Example :

After

```
protected function wrapEJsonPath($value, $delimiter = '->')
{
```

I want

```
protected function wrapEJsonPath($value, $delimiter = '->')
{
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/ked.log', "\n protected function wrapEJsonPath", FILE_APPEND);
```

How can I extract function name and add it into the next line that will be added.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: See also [Insert line after first match using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-first-match-using-sed)