# Failed to write new line after certain match using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nginx, sed

I am trying to write new line after some match found using Dockerfile but its not working as per my code. I am explaining my code below.

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/ubot-nginx.conf`::

```
server {

    listen 90;
    server_name ubot_nginx;

    location / {
        # proxy_pass http://flask_app:5005;
        try_files $uri @app;

        # Do not change this
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }

    location /site {
        # rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
        # root /static;
        alias /app/static/angular;
    }
}
```

In the above file I need to write some new line `i.e-try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;` after `alias /app/static/angular;` so for that I am using below command in my `Dockerfile`.

`RUN sed '/^alias /app/static/angular.*/a try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;' /etc/nginx/conf.d/ubot-nginx.conf`

I need here when the image will built the new line given above should be written as per particular match found which is not happening in my case. Please anybody can help me on this ?

Comment: if you want in-place file edit with sed use `-i` parameter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-match-using-sed

Comment: I dont want to replace add new line after some match found.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you want to end up with, but something like `sed -i -E 's;^(\s*alias /app/static/angular.*);\1\n\ttry_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;' /etc/nginx/conf.d/ubot-nginx.conf` ?

Comment: Your call of sed only send result to standard output and doesn’t change file. If you want to change file (it is called in-place edit) you must use `-i` parameter.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, your suggestion worked but its ignoring `;` after `try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html =404` which caused error in nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sed -i -E 's|^(\s*alias /app/static/angular.*)|\1\n\ttry_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;|' /etc/nginx/conf.d/ubot-nginx.conf`