# How to put text into a file under a specific line in Bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I want a Bash script that puts `userinput` into a file called `software.txt`. But I need the `userinput` to be under a specific line `#addedsoftware` in `software.txt`. The script should be able to add `useriput` multiple times into this file. Is this something that can be achieved with something like `sed`?
When i ran `sed '/#TESTING/a some text here' software.txt` it did not add it to the file. Then i ran `sed '/#TESTING/a some text here' > software.txt` This one just adds whatever keys i press after the command is ran.

Edit i got it working with.: `sed -i '/#TESTING/a some text here' file`

Comment: Does [Insert line after match using `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/) or [How to insert text after a certain string in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121161/) answer your question?

Comment: The first one did help but i am facing a problem.``` sed '/#TESTING/a some text here' software.txt``` does not actually put it in the file it just displays it as a one time thing.

Comment: Right, depending on your environment you would either to do an inline edit via `sed -i '...` or writing the result into another file via `> software.txt.updated.`

Comment: The information on how you tried _sed_ should be in your question, not in a comment. You can edit your question (there is a tiny _edit_ link below your question).

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work? It takes the `software.txt` file and splits it into two parts, top and bottom. Top is everything up to the specified line and bottom is everything after that line. Then it puts the `software.txt` file back together with the user input between the two parts.

For example say your software.txt file looks like this.

`software.txt`

```
# Software.txt

Line 3
Line 4
Line 4
Line 6

# Put user input below this line.

Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
```

`insert_user_input.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read user input.
echo -n "Enter input: "
read user_input

software_txt_top_half=$(sed '/# Put user input below this line./q' software.txt)

software_txt_bottom_half=$(sed '1,/# Put user input below/d' software.txt)

# Insert user input into software.txt after specified line.
cat << EOF > software.txt
$software_txt_top_half
$user_input
$software_txt_bottom_half
EOF
```

Then after running the script it would look like this,

```
$ ./insert_user_input.sh 
Enter input: asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
```

```
# Software.txt

Line 3
Line 4
Line 4
Line 6

# Put user input below this line.
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf

Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
```

Comment: that doesnt really make use of sed in any meaningful way.. and instead of echoing over and over you could just use cat. your most critical piece is using grep and awk more than sed...

Comment: As per your suggestions, I've replaced the multiple echo statements with a heredoc and replaced the grep and awk commands with sed expressions. Thank you for the feedback.