# how to add new line before 10 line to match word on text file using shell script

Tags: shell

I tried using this command, but it didn't work for me.
If i execute the below command,

```
 #!/bin/bash

# set the path to your file
file_path="/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"


# set the word you want to search for
search_word="Settings for a TLS enabled server"


# get the line number where the word is found
line_number=$(grep -n "$search_word" $file_path | cut -d: -f1)


# calculate the line number where you want to insert the new line
insert_line=$((line_number-10))


USAGE=$(cat <<-END
    location /nginx-status {
             stub_status on;
             allow all;
    }
END

)


# insert the new line using sed
sed -i "${insert_line}i $USAGE" $file_path
```

I need to add below line, Before 10 line to "**Settings for a TLS enabled server**" in **Nginx.conf** file.

```
location /nginx-status {
stub_status on; 
allow all; 
}
```

Looking forward as in the image below.
[Expecting_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwVYC.png)

Comment: this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-match-using-sed

Comment: Please use text rather than images for the expected output. The images are usually a pain to read.

Comment: I want "Insert 10 line before match" in the conditional, But the link only says "after match".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sed -i '10ilocation /nginx-status {\nstub_status on; \nallow all; \n}' $path/nginx.conf`

EDIT:
This works:

`sed -i "$(echo $insert_line)i $(echo $USAGE)" $file_path`

Comment: But it doesn't have any command to search specific line.

Comment: Thanks, kindly mark this as an answer if you think it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is a simple awk in combination with `tac`

```
awk '(NR==FNR) { to_print=to_print ORS $0; next }
     /Settings for a TLS enabled server/{n=10}
     {print; n--}(n==0){print to_print}
    ' <(tac insert_file.txt) <(tac update_file) | tac > update_file.new
mv update_file.new update_file
```